# Relative Folders in Wordpress with Compass Sass

Tags: wordpress, sass, path, relative-path, compass-sass

I'm having a problem with the paths in compass, I'm developing a wordpress theme with sass-compass using this structure:

```
theme-name/  
               /css/style.css  
               /sass/style.scss  
               /images  
               /fonts
```

I want to respect this structure cause the stylesheet is already written using paths like:

```
h1 { background-image: url('images/sprite.png'); }
```

so since the stylesheet is inside the css folder that compass create I would have to rename all images paths to `url('../images/sprite.png')` or place the images folder inside the css folder for this to work without modifying, but that is not optimal in this situation, I need to find a way to make this work without modifying the stylesheet, I tried with the `config.rb` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has some specific rules, namely a style.css must be in the theme root for the theme to work. So you have to respect WordPress before sass.

The alternative is to make an assets folder.

/theme
style.css
/assets/morestylesheets.css
/assets/images
etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser, yes I actually bypassed that requirement by placing an empty style.css and in the <head> I placed the path to the sass compiled css/style.css so that's not a problem.